# Bricked Galaxy Tab A. Help? Please

Tags: rooting, samsung, boot-loop, unbricking, twrp

My device: Galaxy Tab A 9.7 (SM-P550) 6.0.1

So installed TWRP via Odin
-success
Then I flashed supersu via twrp 
-success

Then I tried to flash xposed via twrp
-fail

What I think happened was that it was the wrong SDK. I was supposed to install SDK 23 but I installed 21. So then what happened is that it failed and I tried to reboot back into the system and now all it does is reboot back into the TWRP menu and I can get into the lockscreen. So I tried formatting the data, factory resetting, wiping Dalvik/ART Cache and the Cache and tried repairing the file system and still can't boot into the lockscreen.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Wiping `/data` and `/cache` of course won't help because Xposed writes to `/system`.

**EDIT:** As @DeathMaskSalesman points out in the comment, you should try the Xposed uninstaller available in the [official Xposed thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811). If that succeeds then great, you won't need to continue reading the risky part!

The Xposed zip shouldn't have allowed flashing on a wrong SDK at all, but now that the damage is done, back up data (internal storage) via TWRP first (you've already done a factory reset so I assume no app data needs to be backed up), then flash a factory firmware available at [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-P550/) with Odin to get a fresh start.

Comment: Also, quite a coincidence I get to answer your question again in hours, eh? :)

Comment: You may want to link back to the **Xposed Uninstaller**, which you can find at XDA here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Ah derp, forgot about the uninstaller O_o (never used it myself) I'll include this shortly, thanks!